# Leaflet.Editable for Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to get to grips with Leaflet in Shiny for R. I'm happy with handling the display capability. My main aim is for the user to be able to interact with the user interface to be able to add their own points and polygons and to edit geographies and their attributes when they need to, too. The layers will be pre-existing in most cases.

The extension [`Leaflet.Editable`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) does everything I need it to do from what I can see, but unless I am mistaken does not (yet?) appear to be implemented in the Leaflet for R library. [`Leaflet.Draw`](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html) which is included in [`leaflet.extras`](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras) for R appears to be an alternative.

My question is:

- is there an implementation of `Leaflet.Editable` that I've simply missed?
- If there isn't, what do people recommend for drawing / editing points and polygons, including editing attributes?

Comment: Could be useful: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/01/30/mapedit_intro.html

Comment: Thanks. That does look interesting, although it is apparently still in its infancy - I'm a little wary of adopting something which is going through rapid change. But I will certainly investigate.